# What is Bool<true> in C++ - is it from boost?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use some sample code and my compiler won't compile this line:

```
static void exitActions(Host& h, Bool<true>) {}
```

Compiler is MS VS2005.  I don't recognise Bool - so not sure how to replace it.  Is this default parameter equivalent:

```
static void exitActions(Host& h, bool b = true) {}
```

The sample is from http://accu.org/index.php/journals/252.  The code is just snippets in the text - no snippet about what is #include'd - so hard to work out.  There is no definition for a Bool template.

Comment: Bool<true> is a type, and excitActions is probably overloaded based on this type. Could you add the error message you are seeing to the question?

Comment: Well, any references in `exitActions` to the bool argument are probably going to be messed up.  If you were to change all references to type `bool`, you probably wouldn't see things come crashing down, but think of this as an preliminary answer until some much smarter answers.

Comment: what happens when you place the cursor on `Bool<true>` and use "Go to definition"?

Comment: where'd you get the sample code from ?

Comment: @Pablo - probably here? :
http://accu.org/index.php/journals/252

Comment: It's not from Boost, the equivalent there is `boost::true_type`/`boost::integral_constant<bool, true>`. I'm assuming this is an instance of tag dispatching -- you can look that technique up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess `Bool` is defined like

```
template <bool B> struct Bool{};
```

You can use this for some rudimentary pattern matching:

```
void exitActions(Bool<true>)  { std::cout << "called with true\n"; }
void exitActions(Bool<false>) { std::cout << "called with false\n"; }

int main()
{
  exitActions(Bool<true>());  // prints "called with true"
  exitActions(Bool<false>()); // prints "called with false"
}
```

This of course only makes sense if you overload `Bool<true>` with `Bool<false>`. But in the source http://accu.org/index.php/journals/252 (guessed by Marcin), this is the case.

There is also a similar function call

```
Tran<T,S,T>::entryActions(host_, Bool<false>());
```

Comment: Using this definition allows me to compile the program, thank you. Is there a name for this style of programming or a web link.  It is like an overloaded function?  One or other is called dependent on whether you pass true or false I guess?  As you say it only really makes sense in context of rest of the code - I will study it more.

Comment: I've never seen that before in C++ (in other programming languages this is called pattern matching, as already written). Normally you would write something like `template <> void exitActions<true>(){...}` and `template <> void exitActions<false>(){...}`. But since this was often used he may decided to shorten that by introducing this `Bool` type.